# Base Exception Class for GCP Python Library: "google-api-python-client"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-api-python-client

I am using google-api-python-client library, provided by Google Cloud.
I am using lot of methods from it, to operate on compute-engine resources (Disks, instances, snapshots etc)
But while doing lot of operations, for better handling and resilient code, i should add `try..catch` blocks & while adding the blocks, i realized that Google-Cloud doesn't provide any basic Exception class.

Worst case that i have thought of is:

```
try:
 <code>
except:
 <prompt error>
```

But i believe this isn't the right way to do.

Am i missing something ? or the exception handler isn't provided by GCP-Library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gone through the documentation and the Error stack that API returns & i was able to figure out the way to handle errors to handle exceptions in our code.

So, Unlike you mentioned, it is possible..!

Using following way, we could handle the errors/exceptions.

```
import oauth2client.client
from googleapiclient import discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

#
# prepare credentials dictionary
#

try:
    compute = discovery.build(
            "compute", "v1", credentials=credentials)
except oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError as e:
    print 'Error > ', e.message
except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
    reason = str(e._get_reason).split("\"")[-2]
    print 'Error > ', reason
```

I hope, this is helpful!

These two are the most common errors that come up. There might be other errors, which is completely dependent on case.

But all the errors should be present in **`googleapiclient.errors class`**

@Bill Prin, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `google-api-python-client` does not have the exception classes you are looking for.

The `google-api-python-client` library is an older library that is supported but not actively developed. The client calling code is all autogenned and it's a very generic client for a lot of APIs so there aren't many meaningful exceptions coded in there other than at the network/transport/HTTP layer.

Development going forward is on [google-cloud-python](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-python) library, which is a mix of hand-written libraries and autogenerated ones. You may note that not all APIs, including compute, are there yet, although they will be in time. The new autogenerated code will focus more on idiomatic language patterns.

The new library has some more specific exceptions, but if you have any ideas on how to improve it further I'd describe your ideas as a Github issue on the `google-cloud-python` client library.

Comment: Thanks @Bill, So no exception handling for google-api-python-client ? Should i port my code to google-cloud-python library ?

Comment: I could find this link, where the APIs and details are very nicely mentioned. [link](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/python/latest/index.html), do you know similar to this for `google-cloud-python` library?

Comment: Here are the docs for [google-cloud-python(https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) .You should use google-cloud-python if it supports your API. If it doesn't, you can stick with `google-api-python-client`,  I am just explaining why there's no new active feature development, which means exception improvements could go in `google-cloud-python` but not `google-api-python-client`.

Comment: check the above answer mentioned by me, and let me know if i'm right.